# Dell Windows 10 PC stuck on desktop refreshing

Tags: windows, windows-10, dell-inspiron

I'm having a problem with my Dell Insipiron 14 3000 series, whereby it’s constantly refreshing at the desktop screen almost at 10 second intervals or less.

I can’t seem to do anything about the problem as it’s not giving me enough time to open the taskbar and all. This started when I sent an Archicad file to my pc and before the file finished sending it started flickering. I’ve forced shutdown 3 times but the problem is persisting.

Answer (score 0):

If on the task manager the screen does not flicker,
Please clear & reset windows store cache with WSReset.exe command. Right click windows logo, click Command Prompt(Admin), type WSReset.exe onto the command prompt. Windows Store will open and you’ll get a conformation message saying that: The cache for the Store was cleared.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways:

**1. Check to see if Task Manager flickers**

Open Task Manager by pressing the **Ctrl + Shift + Esc** keys on the keyboard at the same time. If that doesn't work, right-click the **Start**  button in the lower-left corner of your screen and then select **Task Manager**.

(1)If Task Manager doesn't flicker, an app is probably causing the problem.

(2)If Task Manager does flicker, a display driver is probably causing the problem.

**2. Update an incompatible app**

Three apps were previously known to cause screen flickering in Windows 10: Norton AV, iCloud, and IDT Audio. In most cases, updating the app or contacting the app manufacturer for an update will fix the problem.

**3. Update your display driver**

To update your display driver, you'll need to start your PC in safe mode, uninstall your current display adapter, and then check for driver updates.

(1)Start your PC in safe mode, then right-click the **Start**  button and select **Device Manager.**

(2)Expand the **Display adapters** section, right-click the listed adapter, then select **Uninstall** device. Select the **Delete the driver software for this device** check box, then select **Uninstall** and restart your PC.

(3)After your PC restarts, press the **Windows logo key  + I** on your keyboard to open Settings. If that doesn't work, select the **Start**  button and then select **Settings**.

(4)From Settings, select **Update & security > Windows Update > Check for updates**.

Note: If you have multiple display adapters, you'll need to disable the added adapter (often an Intel HD 400 or AMD Radeon HD 4200) by right-clicking it from the list in Device Manager and selecting Disable > Yes. Then, turn off your PC, disconnect installation or recovery media (if you're using it), and turn your PC back on. If that doesn't fix the flickering, restart your PC in safe mode, re-enable the added display adapter, and then disable the other adapter.

**4.Type Troubleshooting Control Panel onto the [Cortana] search box, 'View All', and then run windows store apps troubleshooter**.